# Why Botframework bot only works only on Emulator and none of the other channels?

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, botframework

### Bot Info

- Bot handle: Medibot_medibuddy
- App ID: dcda60fe-72d4-4796-a728-de8fa3aef2a5
- SDK Platform: Node.js
- SDK Version: Latest
- Active Channels: WebChat, Facebook, Skype
- Deployment Environment: Azure App Service

### Issue Description

Our bot (Medibot, https://medibotmb.azurewebsites.net) has suddenly stopped working on all channels including WebChat. It works perfectly on Emulator though. We've been trying to debug this issue since days and have not been successful with any solutions/suggestions online. I've tried using Log stream and debug console to catch exceptions but there aren't any.

### Code Example

The code is hosted in https://github.com/nirmalrayan/medibot

### Reproduction Steps

1. Visit medibotmb.azurewebsites.net. This should open WebChat channel's index.html document.
2. The page tries to load for a long time and throws HTTP status: 500, HTTP subStatus: 1001, HTTP Reason: Internal Server Errror.
3. Bot framework displays the error message 'There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout' for Facebook and Web Chat channels.

### Expected Behavior

1. Render index.html page with Web Chat iframe.
2. After the user sends first message, the bot welcomes with a hero card.

### Actual Results

Nothing happens. The page does not get rendered. No exception in thrown in log stream while testing. Even botframework 'Test' does not throw any error in Azure app service log stream.

<kbd>node.js</kbd>

Comment: Suggesting that your problem is somehow more urgent that everyone else's (or the persons own work etc) doesn't usually lead into positive things

Comment: Please try implementing a custom state client using the botbuilder-azure npm package.  https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/21/saving-state-azure-nodejs/

Comment: What is the exact SDK version?

Comment: When I checked your bot server just now, I got a "Server Not Found" error.  It appears your bot server is not online anymore.

Comment: If you are still having problems, please open an issue here --> https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/new

Comment: As per your suggestion, I've opened the issue in the url you had mentioned. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3895

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the iframe code in the index.html of https://medibotmb.azurewebsites.net

Comment: That's because index.html is currently not getting rendered in any browser. The code is available at https://github.com/nirmalrayan/medibot and the iframe is inside chat-box-container div

Comment: I just tested the index.html locally and this works just fine, the bot is responding

Comment: This issue has come back to the same bot. I destroyed the entire resource group from Azure and re-created everything, the issue still persists. Currently my bot credentials are:
Bot handle: medibot_4ttx4fdwLSX
App ID: e3c69ebc-068b-4fa6-a18e-b42b8311adeb
SDK Platform: Node.js
SDK Version: Latest
Active Channels: WebChat, Skype
Deployment Environment: Azure App Service

Comment: There seems to be a serious bug in botframework. My code works well and pretty fast in emulator but doesn't work on any other channel.